# "Cannot find name 'tinymce' ts(2304)" After Supposedly NPM Installing Types

Tags: typescript, tinymce

I'm making a TypeScript-coded web app to run in SharePoint (specifically not Node!!) and which will include use of this useful editor TinyMCE.

I usually have no problem getting types I need through the `npm i --save-dev @types/<system/project>` terminal command to keep the TS checker happy. It works for `jquery`, `bootbox`, etc. I can run through the `index.d.ts` files to get an idea of what's going on.

But not `tinymce`: It has the name in comments in the `index.d.ts` file, but not in code. There are some exported objects like `EditorManager`, and so on, but the instruction is to reference it as `tinymce`.

What must be done to fix this error, as I want script properly checked for this name? (Which means `declare const tinymce: any;` is not an acceptable solution, something I think I found mentioned elsewhere).